# How to process 100 Million + text lines at once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that reads and processes text file line by line, problem is my text file has between 1,5-2 billion lines and it is taking forever. Is there away to process over 100 Million lines at the same time?

```
from cryptotools.BTC.HD import check, WORDS



with open("input.txt", "r") as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        for word in WORDS:
            mnemonic = stripped_line.format(x=word)
            if check(mnemonic):
               print(mnemonic)
               with open("print.txt", "a") as i:
                   i.write(mnemonic)
                   i.write("\n")
```

Input file has the following sample lines:

```
gloom document {x} stomach uncover peasant sock minor decide special roast rural
happy seven {x} gown rally tennis yard patrol confirm actress pledge luggage
tattoo time {x} other horn motor symbol dice update outer fiction sign
govern wire {x} pill valid matter tomato scheme girl garbage action pulp
```

Comment: Are you able to open your file and load it completely into memory? if not you can not process it "at the same time". 1.5 - 2 billion lines of 4 letter words (avg) + newline are 2.000.000.000*5Byte (if stored as ascii and not utf) - thats 10.000.000.000 Byte, wich is  10+ Gigabyte in 1 file. It should take forever.

Comment: Your code is not a [mre] - we do not know the input-files structure, `def check(str)` is missing. [edit] and fix.

Comment: How can I load the file into memory, can you give an example? new at python and just read up on memory constraints. I thought it would be best to get someone to modify my code to point me in the right direction

Comment: You wont be able to because reading a 10GB file into memory and splitting to list will give you a MemoryError. If you do not know how to load a complete text file into memory you are multiple _weeks_ to _months_ away from being able to split and parallel process a 10gig file.

Comment: You may start by speeding up your current code before looking into multiprocessing.  For instance, for large files opening/closing file in a loop is slow (i.e. `with open("print.txt", "a") as i:`) as shown by [keep file open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679495/python-when-writing-to-a-large-file-keep-the-file-open-or-to-open-it-and-appen)

Comment: Yes, I realized my code maybe to simple for such a huge task thats why as good practice I cam for advice on where to improve

Comment: The "proper" way to handle this is to not use a single file. Split your 100M line file into 100 files with 1M lines, for example, then process each of those in parallel. Research: **mapreduce**

Comment: Any idea on the time/complexity of `check(mnemonic)`?  This would help in determining if you're IO limited (use multithreading) vs. CPU limited (use multiprocessing).

Comment: How often is `check(mnemonic)` true?

Comment: For each line in the text file being processed, its Bip39 validation check

Comment: @DarrylG Looks like it's doing SHA256 checks, so presumably that file opening/closing gets executed very rarely.

Comment: @KellyBundy--WORDS has 2048 elements in it and `check(mnemonic)` is True ~120 times/2048 for each line.  So, this will be a large number of opening/closings (i.e. ~120 x number of lines in the input file).

Comment: @X-Strong for your example data I'm getting ~120 lines for each line of your input.  Does that mean for 1.5-2 billion lines you would expect 120 times this?

Comment: Correct, the code checks for valid BIP39 checksum of 2048 words which on average is 120-130 lines per line input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To process 100 million lines at once you would have to have 100 million threads. Another approach to improve the speed of your code is to split the work among different threads (lower than 100 million).
Because write and read operations from file are not asynchronous, you would be better off with reading all the file at the beginning of your program and write out thr processed data at the end. In the code below i will assume you do not care about the order at which wou write the file out. But if order is important you could set a dictionary that has as key the positional value of the current line being elaborated by a specific thread and at the end sort accordingly.

```
import concurrent.futures as cf

N_THREADS = 20
result = []

def doWork(data):
    for line in data:
        #do what you have to do
        result.append(mnemonic)

m_input = open("input.txt", "r")
lines = [line for line in m_input]
#the data for the threads will be here
#as a list of rows for each thread
m_data= { i: [] for i in range(0, N_THREADS)} 
for l, n in zip(lines, range(0, len(lines))):
    m_data[n%N_THREADS].append(l)
'''
If you have to trim the number of threads uncomment these lines
m_data= { k:v for k, v in m_data.items() if len(v) != 0}
N_THREADS = N_THREADS if len(m_data) > N_THREADS else len(m_data)
if(N_THREADS == 0): 
    exit()
'''
with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_THREADS) as tp:
    for d in m_data.keys():
        tp.submit(doWork,m_data[d])
    
#work done
output = open("print.txt", "w")
for item in result:
    output.write(f"{item}\n")
output.close()
```

Change the number of threads as you find most efficient.

---

### Edit (with memory optimizations):

The code above, while being extrimely fast, uses a significant amount of memory because loads the whole file in memory and then works on it.

You then have two options:

- split your file in multiple smaller files, from my testing (see below) using a test file with ~10 million lines, the program run extremely fast actually, but used up to 1.3 GB of ram.
- use the code down here where i load one line at a time and assign that line to a thread that works on that line and then pushes the data to a thread that is only responsible to write to the file. In this way the memory usage significantly drops but the execution time rises.

The code below, reads a single line from the file (the one with 10 million lines that is approximately ~500 MB) and then sends that data to a class that manages a fixed number of threads. Currently I spawn a new thread every time one finishes, actually could be more efficient, using always the same threads and use a queue for each thread. Then I spawn a `writer` thread that its only work is to write to the `out.txt` file that will contain the result. In my testing I only read the text file and write the same lines in another file. 
What i found out is the following (using the 10 million lines file):

- Original code: it took **14.20630669593811** seconds and used **1.301 GB** (average usage) of ram and 10% cpu usage
- Updated code: it took **1230.4356942176819** seconds and used **4.3 MB** (average usage) of ram and 10% cpu usage with the internal parameters as in the code below.

The timed results were obtained using the same number of threads for both the programs. 
From those results it is evident how the memory optimized code runs significantly slower while using way less ram. You can tune the internal parameters such as the number of threads or the maximum queue size to improve the performance, keeping in mind that would affect memory usage. After a lots of tests, I would suggest to split the file in multiple subfiles that can fit in your memory and run the original version of the code (see above), because the tradeoff between time and speed is simply not justified in my opinion. 
Here I put the code I optimized for memory cunsumption **but** keep in mind that is **NOT** optimized in any significant way as far as thread management goes, one suggestion would be to use always the same threads and use multiple queues to pass the data to those threads. 
Here I leave the code i used to optimize memory consumption (and yes is way more complex than the one above XD, and maybe more than what it needs to be) :

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import os
import queue

MAX_Q_SIZE = 100000
m_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=MAX_Q_SIZE)
end_thread = object()

def doWork(data):
    #do your work here, before
    #checking if the queue is full,
    #otherwise when you finish the 
    #queue might be full again
    while m_queue.full():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pass
    
    m_queue.put(data)

def writer():
    #check if file exists or creates it
    try:
        out = open("out.txt", "r")
        out.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        out = open("out.txt", "w")
        out.close()
    out = open("out.txt", "w")
    _end = False
    while True:
        if m_queue.qsize == 0:
            if _end:
                break
            continue
        try:
            item = m_queue.get()
            if item is end_thread:
                out.close()
                _end = True
                break
            global written_lines
            written_lines += 1
            out.write(item)
        except:
            break


class Spawner:
    def __init__(self, max_threads):
        self.max_threads = max_threads
        self.current_threads = [None]*max_threads
        self.active_threads = 0
        self.writer = Thread(target=writer)
        self.writer.start()

    def sendWork(self, data):
        m_thread = Thread(target=doWork, args=(data, ))
        replace_at = -1
        if self.active_threads >= self.max_threads:
            #wait for at least 1 thread to finish
            while True:
                for index in range(self.max_threads):
                    if self.current_threads[index].is_alive() :
                        pass
                    else:
                        self.current_threads[index] = None
                        self.active_threads -= 1
                        replace_at = index
                        break
                if replace_at != -1:
                    break
                #else: no threads have finished, keep waiting
        if replace_at == -1:
            #only if len(current_threads) < max_threads
            for i in range(len(self.current_threads)):
                if self.current_threads[i] == None:
                    replace_at = i
                    break
        self.current_threads[replace_at] = m_thread
        self.active_threads += 1
        m_thread.start()

    def waitEnd(self):
        for t in self.current_threads:
            if t.is_alive():
                t.join()
            self.active_threads -= 1
        while True:
            if m_queue.qsize == MAX_Q_SIZE:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue
            m_queue.put(end_thread)
            break
        if self.writer.is_alive():
            self.writer.join()


start_time = time.time()

spawner = Spawner(50)
with open("input.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        spawner.sendWork(line)

spawner.waitEnd()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

You can remove the prints for the time, I left those just for reference to know how I computed the time the program took to run, as well below you find the screenshots of the execution of the two programs from task manager.

- Memory optimized version:
  [image: Memory optimized version]
- Original version (I forgot to expand the terminal process when taking the screenshot, anyway the memory usage of subprocesses of the terminal is negligibile with respect to the one used by the program and the 1.3 GB of ram is accurate):
  [image: Original version]

Comment: This is a very good start let me work on this code sample and revert, thank you very much

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, for a 10GB file and limited memory space, `[line for line in m_input]`, which is the same as `list(m_inout)`, is almost certainly going to fail

Comment: Sure, memory limitation is of course a main problem in this case. But a similar approach with up to a certain amount of lines for each iteration could be taken reducing or at least allowing the file to be read in chunks.

Comment: For those looking at more generic work to be done, note that `doWork()` is currently ok in that `append()` is threadsafe but be aware that other stuff added to `doWork()` may not be.

Comment: The code above is giving this error --> for l, n in zip(lines, len(lines)):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Yes should be range(0, len(lines)), i edited my answer now, thank you!

Comment: Hi, had time to work on the above code it shows NameError: name 'data_t' is not defined

Comment: Oh yes I mistyped, it should be `m_data`. I fixed the code now. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Concerning the memory usage of the code above, I am currently testing another piece of code that uses significantly less memory (depending on some parameters setting that you can tune as you like) that with a file of 10 million lines (~500MB) uses 100mb of ram (with the parameters I set) instead of 1.3GB that the code above uses. As soon i end testing i will update my answer. Also, as a downside, the new code, while using less memory, is significantly slower :(

Comment: My friend this above script, is a work of art! Cut my work by days...thank you so much. keep being brilliant, thank you :)

Comment: @Armaggheddon if you can read this, is it possible to optimize the first code you have to run on vectorize numba, or numpy and would it increase the speed? Thank you in advance

Comment: Well it could be yes or no. The main problem in speed here is the ability of the "reader" to fill the worker threads so that they have always something to do. Instead of using those libraries I would "invest" some time in changing some of the parameters of the above program to run at the edge of your machine capabilities and, if you feel brave enought, you can try optimizing the communication pipe between the reader and the workers (also keeping the workers always alive and "fixed). And as a disclaimer, I am not aware of "out of the box" capabilities of those libraries mentioned.